# Long running scrapy crawl aborts

Tags: debugging, logging, scrapy

I'm running several spiders over different websites. Most runs take 2 - 3 days and many work fine. But sometimes it happens, that the crawl just stops or crashes?

With:

```
scrapy crawl myspider > logs/myspider.log 2>&1 &
```

I'm writing the output into a file and for one crawl for instance the last entry is:

```
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1975 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 1907 items (at 1 items/min)
```

and it simply stops there. Not dumped any stats and it didn't get to the end of everything.

Now I assume that could be a network issue or similar?
The machine has an average load of 0.10, I'm scrapying with a 40 sec delay and running 5 - 10 spiders. The hardware is old but RAM and CPU are usually bored in `htop`. I didn't change the `LOG_LEVEL` so it should by default be `DEBUG`.

How can I find out what happens?

Comment: One thing I've seen more than once: people using python-requests .get() or else in their spider code, these calls can hang forever if not timeout is explicitly passed (true). That's one thing. You could check if the process is stuck on IO with strace and ss